# <mvc:resources> can I point the location="http:path/to/s3/bucket"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, resources

I am working on a Spring MVC Project, Now I need to move my resources to s3 bucket but I need a mechanism to switch between local and s3 conveniently.
I am having following snippets in my dispatcher-servlet.xml

eg.
for files on same project

```
<mvc:resources location="/app-res/" mapping="/app-res/**"/>
```

for files on local drive i can do

```
<mvc:resources location="file:D:/app-res/" mapping="/app-res/**"/>
```

same way can I do something like

```
<mvc:resources location="http:path/to/s3/bucket" mapping="/app-res/**"/>
```

I have tried to do the same but not able to get to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Profiles is one possible solution:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml

Parameterize the external URL:

```
<mvc:resources location="${path.to.s3.bucket}" mapping="/app-res/**"/>
```

Create some profile definitions:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...">

    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="applicationPropertiesPlaceholder"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:profiles/dev.profile.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>     
    </beans>

    <beans profile="production">
        <bean id="applicationPropertiesPlaceholder"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:profiles/production.profile.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>         
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Create the properties files and then you just need to append `-Dspring.profiles.active=xyz` to your server's JVM args.